# This android statement shows sqlite error

Tags: android

```
int pos=spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
            String temp=(String)spinner1.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            db = openOrCreateDatabase("MY_App_Data", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            ContentValues cvUpdate=new ContentValues();
            cvUpdate.put("msg",msg.getText().toString());
            try
            {

            //public int update (String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) 

            db.update("MY_TABLE",cvUpdate,"column_one="+temp+, null);

            readdata();//method call
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No row found!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

this is not working please help me out i have tried a lot but don't understand whts the wrong

Comment: -1 for catching without logging the full stacktrace and therefore posting an error without a stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

If `temp` is a String you have to add `'`:

```
db.update("MY_TABLE", cvUpdate, "column_one='" +temp +"'", null);
```

If temp is a number you should at least omit the `+`:

```
db.update("MY_TABLE", cvUpdate, "column_one=" +temp, null);
```

**p.s.** best option is to use prepared statements:

```
SQLiteStatement st = db.compileStatement(
                    "UPDATE MY_TABLE SET msg = ? WHERE column_one = ?"); 

st.bindString(1, msg.getText().toString()); 
st.bindString(2, temp); 

st.execute();
```

This allows to bind the right type and thus helps to avoid unnecessary type conversions. Consider opening and closing a transaction (see [`beginTransaction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29) and [`endTransaction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#endTransaction%28%29)) if you have many updates. This has a quite big impact on run time performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
b.update("MY_TABLE",cvUpdate,"column_one="+temp+, null);
```

You are directly adding value (and it's String) for column into statement but **NOT in correct way**. Since you are adding directly values for column(s) you have to wrap them into single quotes - otherwise SQLite will interpret it as next column (that doesn't exist). Also you have one extra plus sign.

So it should be:

```
b.update("MY_TABLE", cvUpdate, "column_one = '" + temp + "'", null);
```

### Recommendation:

Generally is recommended to use parametrized statements because raw statements are not safe and not very human readable. This practise is generally recommended. So it can be rewritten like this:

```
b.update("MY_TABLE", cvUpdate, "column_one = ?", new String[] {temp});
```

Also is a very good practise to store column names as constants in some class. You will avoid type problems (which are very famous).

Comment: Note that values of `whereArgs` are bound as Strings. This might lead to unwanted, implicit type conversions. Best would be to use prepared statements.